# What happened to the Witch King's Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

After the battle when the Witch King of Angmar was defeated his helm and clothing remain.  At this point he either died or dissipated into a bodiless form.   If he was wearing one of the Nine Rings, where did it go after the battle.  If not, is there any evidence of where these were kept?

Comment: Yes, that question states what happened to the Nazgul's rings - Sauron had them, and they would have been destroyed when he was.

Comment: @JasonBaker I wouldn't say it was a duplicate but I agree that the answer given on that one also answers this.  If you want to post hat as an answer I'm happy to accept it.  Otherwise, I would delete the question but there is already one answer.

Comment: And now I see there is already a mechanism for this.  Sorted.

Comment: @Alchymist On this site we close questions as dupes based on the answers, as well as the questions (I understand this makes us a bit special within the network). I still wouldn't delete this question; having dupe questions hanging around can be useful for searching

Comment: Perhaps we should just be less special as per the last meta thread.

Comment: I'm quite happy to have it marked as a duplicate as there is a link to the other answer.  I just didn't want others to be stuck asking a similar question to mine without being able to find the answer.